# stopping a thread in windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, winapi

I have created a thread in windows using C :

```
hookThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, lpStartAddress, NULL, 0, &hookThreadId);
```

Comment: You should specify what exactly you want (there's not really a question, is there?), as "stopping" a thread may refer to _suspending_ it vs _terminating_ it (Luchian Grigore assumed the latter in below answer). It is also unclear in which context you want to do this. Terminating or suspending a thread is not something you normally want to do, unless there's a good reason. Usually you block or sleep when you don't want a thread to do work and return from the thread's entry function when you want it to end. Everything else is unpleasant and risky.

Comment: Is there any question? I would vote for close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`TerminateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

The function you posted does:

```
  PostThreadMessage(hookThreadId, WM_QUIT, (WPARAM) NULL, (LPARAM) NULL);
  WaitForSingleObject(hookThreadHandle, 5000);
```

So it sends a quit message to that thread, and then waits for it to close.

Comment: how does the [function here](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/source/browse/trunk/src/native/windows/NativeThread.c#554) stop the native thread ?

Comment: what is the difference between the 2 methods ?

Comment: @program-o-steve have you tried google?

Comment: `TerminateThread` should probably be renamed into `IntroduceHardestToFindBugsImaginableAreYouMadToUseThis()` - I assume they went with the first because it's slightly shorter :)

Comment: TerminateThread is rarely ever the correct thing to do - per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx): "TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases. You should call TerminateThread only if you know exactly what the target thread is doing, and you control all of the code that the target thread could possibly be running at the time of the termination." Eg: Critical sections and heap locks don't get released, and other nasty stuff...

Comment: ...the right thing to do is to ask the thread to exit and then wait for it to do so, per the sample code above. If the thread is GUI thread, post it a message; if it's a non-GUI thread, use an event or similar to communicate with it. @LuchianGrigore, your answer is correct, but IMO worth emphasizing that Terminate Thread is a *last resort* and should be mentioned with the caveats, not the first thing to list in a reply :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the thread you can use the **TerminateThread()** and if you want to only pause it you can use **SuspendThread()** (to resume it use **ResumeThread()**)

Comment: Note that TerminateThread will likely leak memory and leave shared data and synchronisation objects in an inconsistent or undefined state. Both TerminateThread and SuspendThread can cause deadlocks. You really really really don't want to use these functions, except if there is a very urgent reason.